# How do I check if a column is the result of other columns in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a database with tables has been created before. I'm trying to figure out if a column is a calculation result of other columns.
For example: total = quantity * price. How can I know that the 'total' column is made by the result of 'quantity' and 'price' columns.

I'm expecting something like 'total.TableName' = 'quantity.TableName' * 'price.TableName'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the results where it isn't the case:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE total <> quantity * price;
```

Comment: Yes, look up SQL joins.